# Crypt/decrypt app's code and data Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, cordova

We wanna to Crypt/decrypt app's source code and data. How this can be done and which tech we must have to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this StackOverflow answer as it give a lot of good information on JavaScript Obfuscation which is what you are looking to do:

[How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)